# Functional tests in Java : how to make them run sequentially

Tags: automated-tests, playframework-2.2

I found in Scala there is "sequential" to run test in order.
How do we do with Java ?

I use the default testing framework with real http server as in the doc https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaFunctionalTest

And by the way, how can I make a test wait for Akka schedulers to finish ?

```
@Test
public void testFlashNeedPictureLog() {
    running(testServer(3333), new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            //Run in test

            Akka.system().scheduler().schedule(
                    Duration.create(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
                    Duration.create(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
                    new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //Dont run
                        }
                    },
                    Akka.system().dispatcher()
            );

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: which library are you using? JUnit ? Cucumber ? Another ? Can you share a sample to help ?

Comment: Thanks, I precised my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Play! Framework standart framework for testing is jUnit, we can use a **fix of jUnit**  which enables you to **set tests order alphabetical only**

```
import org.junit.runners.MethodSorters;

import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;
import org.junit.Test;

@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class SampleTest {


   @Test
    public void firstTest() {
        System.out.println("first");
    }

    @Test
    public void secondTest() {
        System.out.println("second");
    }
}
```

(from https://stackoverflow.com/a/13540131/2342528)